# Vuetify v-select multiple must have at least one item selected

Tags: vuetify.js, v-select

I have the following v-select:

```html
<v-select
  flat
  dense
  outlined
  multiple
  small-chips
  deletable-chips
  hide-details
  v-model='chosenStrings'
  label='Strings'
  :items='strings'
  :menu-props='{nudgeBottom: 40}'
>
  <template v-slot:append>
    <v-icon>
      mdi-chevron-down
    </v-icon>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

And this is my data:

```js
strings: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
chosenStrings: ['d']
```

I can't figure out a way to make it have at least one item always selected. Perhaps make an item disabled if it's the only one selected.

I don't see a `required` prop in the documentation. Tried to use `item` slot and provide my own `v-list-item`, but guess didn't do something right, as it also failed.

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64116145/vuetify-multiple-v-select-required-rules-dont-work.

Comment: @TendyTeslo Thank you, but I've already seen that. It only checks to see if an item is selected, but doesn't prevent the removal of the last item. And I need to have at least one selected at all times.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the `deletable-chips` with a condition and add `hide-selected` prop Here is this.

```html
<v-select
  flat
  dense
  outlined
  multiple
  small-chips
  :deletable-chips="chosenStrings.length>1"
  hide-selected
  hide-details
  v-model='chosenStrings'
  label='Strings'
  :items='strings'
  :menu-props='{nudgeBottom: 40}'
>
  <template v-slot:append>
    <v-icon>
      mdi-chevron-down
    </v-icon>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

Comment: Tried that too: it will prevent the removal of the last element with chip, but I still can remove it in the v-select itself.

Comment: please check the demo https://codepen.io/tuhin47/pen/BazgmrY?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks, I did. As I said, it does prevent the removal of the last item with chip, but I'm still able to remove it by opening the v-select menu and clicking on the item.

Comment: `hide-selected` prop may help

Comment: Actually, I just thought of a better idea (since I don't want to hide any strings). Instead of having strings as array in the data property, I'm making use of  `computed` property and I return an array of objects like this: `{text: 'A', value: 'a', disabled: this.chosenStrings.length === 1 && this.chosenStrings.includes('a')}`. Now the last item becomes disabled!